# Powerpoint doesn't let me adjust the height of a cell in a table

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have this table in the beginning:

[image]

There are two rows and one column. I want to add a second subtitle in the second row. To do that I split the second row and create 3 rows.

[image]

I add the colors and the text to get this:

[image]

I now want to change the height of the new cell so that it is the same as the height of the top most cell.

[image]

As a final step, I want to make the font size the same (Arial (body) 32), however if I do it, I get the following:

[image]

It looks the same but it's not. If I go to the layout tab, I get a slightly larger height for the new cell:

[image]

And the problem is that I can not make the height of the second black cell to be 0.79......

Here is the powerpoint file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43005699109731055158

I need some help with this, I have given up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the cell is constrained to the values inside it. in your file, this Cell margins is set to wide, select the cell and from layout, change the cell margins to normal.
[Cell Margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE9iv.png)
[Cell height changed to 0.79](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVC78.png)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After spending an hour on that issue, A simple workaround is just to add new raw, copy the text in the new line (making sure it isn't blowing the line spacing again), and delete the original line...